# TransactionalMap vs SynchronizedMap

Tags: scala, concurrency, synchronization, akka, stm

When should one prefer Akka `TransactionalMap` over regular immutable map mixed in with `SynchronizedMap` and vice versa? (Or am I comparing apples to oranges here?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the transactional map when you want to have transactions.
Use Ctries/ConcurrentHashMap/NonblockingHashMap for mixed read-writes and CAS+immutable.Map for very-very-infrequent writes.